# How to generate Dashboard report for existing JMeter csv/jtl files with tab delimiter

Tags: jmeter, report, performance-testing

I am trying to generate JMeter Dashboard graph for existing results i.e., csv/jtl files.

Following is the csv file content (temp1.csv):

```
timeStamp   elapsed label   responseCode    responseMessage threadName  dataType    success failureMessage  bytes   grpThreads  allThreads  Latency
1475842232895   1158    HTTP Request    200 OK  Thread Group 1-1    text    true        22175   1   1   911
1475842234094   529 HTTP Request    200 OK  Thread Group 2-1    text    true        682 1   1   529
```

Following is the command I ran:

```
jmeter -g J:\temp_ws\temp1.csv -o J:\temp_ws\temp1
```

and delimiter set to `,` in `user.properties`

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=,
```

It is giving the following error I got (from JMeter.log file)

```
FATAL - jmeter.JMeter: An error occurred:  org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Error while processing samples:Consumer failed with message :No column <timeStamp> found in sample metadata <timeStamp   elapsed label   responseCode    responseMessage threadName  dataType    success failureMessage  bytes   grpThreads  allThreads  Latency>, check #jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties to add the missing column
at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:245)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:478)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
```

Then tried to change the delimiter to `\t` in `user.properties` and run the command again to generate the report, I got the following error:

```
2016/10/07 17:59:32 FATAL - jmeter.JMeter: An error occurred:  

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:477)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.<clinit>(ReportGenerator.java:79)
    ... 6 more
```

Please help me how to generate the Dashboard report for tab delimited Jmeter results (either csv/jtl)

Note: For comma delimiter, Dashboard reports are getting generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're facing a bug of 3.0:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60125

It is fixed in nightly build and will be available in 3.1 coming soon.

Meanwhile you can use Nightly Builds:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html